# Why has the author of this code used the .call method? Surely he could have just accessed the prototype?

Tags: javascript

Im looking through some code (unfortunatly the author isnt around anymore) and im wondering why he has used the .call method.

```
hmlPlaylist.prototype.loadVideos = function () {
    var scope = this;

    this.config.scriptUrl = '_HMLPlaylistAjax.aspx?' + Math.random();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: this.config.scriptUrl,
        success: function (d, t, x) {
            scope.loadVideos_callback.call(scope, d);
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
};

hmlPlaylist.prototype.loadVideos_callback = function (data) {
    var jsonData = '';
    var jsonError = false;

    try {
        jsonData = eval("(" + data + ")");
    } catch (jError) {
        jsonError = true;
    }

    if (!jsonError) {

        if (jsonData.playlists.length > 0) {
            this.buildPlaylistList(jsonData.playlists);
        }
        if (jsonData.videos.length > 0) {
            this.buildVideoList(jsonData.videos);
            this.bindVideoNavs();
        }
    }
    else {

        // no json returned, don't do anything
    }
};
```

Obviously he seems to have used it to pass a 'this' reference to the loadVideos_callback method but why? The 'loadVideos_callback' method is attached to the prototype of 'hmlplaylist' which is the 'class'. So if you access this inside the 'loadVideos_callback' method you get to the same thing dont you?

Comment: sorry dude, I clearly need to hit up my optometrist for a better pair of glasses :-)

Comment: thats okay I think you had a valid point, and it has definitely helped me cement the knowledge that 'this' refers to the object that is being referenced by the instantiation should the user of the constuctor function want to use it for that purpose, i.e. a function constuctor. And if they dont then this will refer to window!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, I think you are right (I can't see the code in action).  You still need the closure around scope, but in this case the use of `call` is not necessary.

To pull some of the comments into this answer, `this` is always the context on which the method was invoked.  So if a new instance of `htmlPlayList` was created, and the method invoked on that instance, `this` would be a reference to that instance.

Comment: @pete2k, you can just try it and see if it still works. Besides, you are thinking along the correct path, so even if you are wrong in this case, you are asking the right questions.

Comment: @Pointy, in 'this' case (ha ha ha), how is 'this' not the instance of the htmlPlayList on which the method was invoked, and hence not the instance on which you want to do the load method?

Comment: Because the fact that a function is hooked up to a prototype object has absolutely no effect on what `this` refers to in an invocation of the function.  Note for example that the exact same function could be referred to by 3000 different prototype objects.  The association with a prototype object is used by the runtime to **find** the function when calls are made through an object (with "object.foo()"), but it has no effect on `this`.

Comment: @pointy, i guess my point is if he actually has an instance of htmlPlayList, then this in the method invocation would be that instance. right?  The fact that he is passing `scope` to the `call` method as the context on which to execute the method, where scope is `this`, indicates that he doesn't need to use `call`.

Comment: The `this` pointer in "loadVideos" would be a reference to the instance **if** the instance is used to make the function call.  However, without using "call", the value of `this` in the callback function would just be `window`.  This is all extremely easy to see in action if you just try it out.

Comment: @pointy, he is passing `scope` into the call method as the context.  o_O.  If the `this` that is used to close in `scope` is not the instance on which the method was invoked, then there is no way that code would work because there are no other variables that could be the context.  In other words, if `this` is `window`, then `scope` is going to be window too.

Comment: oops I see what you mean now :-)  I must need a nap.

Comment: @pointy -- i was never disagreeing with you in the general sense.  Thats why a call method exists.  But in this case, I think its clear its not needed. ;)

Comment: so your saying that if the user of this class always calls var v = new hmlplaylist() then tese calls to .call would not be needed. But if they wanted to use the functions on their own then they would need them?

Comment: great im glad we are all in agreement. Thanks alot for helping me get my head around this potentially confusing code!